# Only 4 partitions for Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I have a disk with **X**GB space. I want to have only 4 Partitions as follows:

1. /
2. /xxxx
3. /home
4. /swap *`double RAM size`*

I want /home to be as large as possible to keep any data regarding users even web server's virtual host to save them in the case of needing install new fresh Ubuntu or any other Linux distro.

My question: the /xxxx, What is the mount name of it? and what is the **least size** should be allocated for it? It is supposed to handle the OS files and other installed program and application such as, Gimp, Netbeans IDE, Java, Games, etc. From Windows point of view, it should work like both `C:\Windows` and `C:\Program Files` directories.

Comment: That's not the way Linux distros work. You can't put OS files and programs like Gimp to some arbitrary /xxxx location. You can have /usr as a separate partition, but I don't see any benefits of doing it on one HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by no means an exact science. Many people will have different preferences or recommendations.

Here is what I tend to use (except I don't use swap):

1. /  (root, approx 30GB. It's better to not have to resize this later)
2. /boot (boot/efi, approx 1GB, min 512MB)
3. /home (disk_size - root_size - boot_size - swap_size)
4. /swap (if you have tons of ram you might not even need a swap partition unless you need hibernation)

Your OS/Programs go into the root, or can be installed into your home folder.  The programs themselves are not what is important to keep, it's the program data that is stored in your $HOME folder that is important to retain between installations.

Comment: So, could I understand that `/` the *root* partition should handles OS and apps so 30 GB should be enough?.
By the way, without Swap you could not able to do Hibernate!

Comment: Yes, OS and programs mainly would go in root `/`. Large programs such as steam games would generally be installed to your home folder by default, so they wont exhaust the 30GB root.